# Pagination count can be changed by direct query string manipulation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, pagination

When viewing question lists there are several options down the bottom to view 15, 30 or 50 records per page.

If the user enters some other number it still works. I entered **1** at the end of the query string and it worked (showing only one record).

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&pagesize=1

If this is an intentional "feature" it's insane.

Comment: *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"* "Then stop doing it"

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ well there is no such thing, this site is made for helping each other not insulting the members. its our duty to help improve this site.

Comment: @AtifImtiaz How am I insulting you? I'm pointing out that you *deliberately* changed a parameter, causing the observed behavior. I fail to see the problem here.

Comment: What about it makes it a "bug?"  Apparently we can limit the number of results per page by an arbitrary number... they give us three common options... why is that a problem?

Comment: @JeffMercado i think user should only be allowed to select the options rather than writing his own number and making a way.

Comment: Interesting way to find out how many questions are in a tag.

Comment: @Atif, **why** do you think that this restriction should be in place, and merits developer effort to make it so?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ yes i was telling you the same that anyone can have his own way and change the number whatever he likes. i see it as a problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta have you ever heard the term usablity? if that should be the feature then user should have a dropdown or something else called page size where he can select. there is no point of making the user writing that into the query string. everyone doesn't know how to use query string.

Comment: @AtifImtiaz How is that a usability issue? Someone who doesn't know they can change the value can still use the default options just fine. Adding a dropdown adds needless clutter to the user interface.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ but in that case they would only be limited to the default options right? they cannot set the custom size right? so every user should be treated the same and must have the choice to avail same things. what you are saying is that the one who dont know how to pass a value into query string would only be bound to default options. come one!

Comment: @AtifImtiaz Well, it is what it is. I don't see this as an issue and 8 people agree with me so far.

Comment: All I can say is, Atif, you have a long hill to climb if you're asserting that all options exposed through query string parameters must necessarily also be exposed through UI elements, and wish to convince others of that. The rhetoric you're using tells me you find it hard to see the other side of the argument - I encourage you to challenge your assumptions.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ i see it as an issue, and everytime majority is not right. i suspect the opposite

Comment: oh @MichaelPetrotta i think you also still have a hill to climb. that was my own point of view and if it condradicts with your's than it not necessary that i am wrong.

Comment: If you change the number and it does not return that many results, then it's a bug. But if you enter 77 and it returns 77, then it's as expected

Comment: @random please read the whole story i wrote above there. as i am not going to again type or copy the same thing twice. and i wrote 9999 but it only returned 15 results. so what now?

Comment: You might not be wrong, you're right about that, Atiz. If you can write up a justification for your belief, please do. I'm willing to be persuaded.

Comment: what if you put 2147483647 as the parameter. does it work ok? what about 2147483648? How about -1?

Comment: i agree with @doug65536

Comment: Judging by the very high quality of the web programming in SO, I'd assume their backend is okay with wild parameters. But if its trivially exposed on the query string, they're almost certainly validating it. It's worth checking though.

Comment: You can only use values from 1 to 50. If you use a value outside this range, it falls back to the last valid option used. So clearly there's validation going on the server side, which means this is almost certainly intentional. cc @doug65536

Comment: yes @doug65536 if they want the user to make an input they should not be checking the query string for values like 81238231289. it should return 81238231289 records. but if the page size is meant to be bound then it should be in UI element.

Comment: yea @NullUserExceptionอ_อ i know that it is intentional since it checks the bigger values. but it would take very less effort to resolve that flaw. but i think everyone here is only concerned about discussion not resolution

Comment: There's no "flaw" to be resolved. This is working 100% as intended.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ perhaps i should talk to someone with right authority to change that.

Comment: Please, please, please never work in QA.

Comment: @AtifImtiaz Don't waste your time. Meta is the right channel and the moderators are most likely as high an "authority" as you're going to get.

Comment: @Bart the topic is closed why do you want to start again?

Comment: @AtifImtiaz Maybe because you said this: *"perhaps i should talk to someone with right authority to change that."* ???

Comment: There are now two posts that request this to be disabled: [Avoid possible CSRF attacks by saving sort selection only when actually clicking](/q/278245/289905), [Changes to answer sorting menu: moving menu, "Newest" sort option, renaming sort options](/a/375952/289905).

Answer (score 12):

If a user wanted to only page through 13 questions at a time, they can do that if they wanted to hack the URL.

If you wanted to page through one question at a time, for whatever reason, you could change the URL to `&pagesize=1`.

15, 30 and 50 are the default page size options presented. 50 questions is the maximum. You can try and enter a higher number, but you're not going to get past that upper limit.

It is as the good fjord intended.

Comment: I'd be more happy with 16 questions at a time, since I can find my page by shifting my question index right 4 bits :P

Comment: and i would be happy with 81723 questions :p